# jquery $.getJSON - handling result types

Tags: jquery

Using $.getJSON my result can be empty, a single value or a list of values.

If the result contains a single value i can access the data via result.someReturnedValue however if the result contains a list i have to loop through the result data using array syntax to access the data E.g. result[i].someReturnedValue

Now i dont want to write the same code twice to handle each type of result. (I'm appending the result to DOM elements and the code is getting large when i have to account for both notations) Is there a generic way i can handle the result to prevent this duplication?

Example of single result;

```
    $('div[id="'+divId+'"]').append("<td>" + result.someValue1+ "</td>");
$('div[id="'+divId+'"]').append("<td>" + result.someValue2+ "</td>");
$('div[id="'+divId+'"]').append("<td>" + result.someValue2+ "</td>");
```

Example of multiple results:

```
    $('div[id="'+divId+'"]').append("<td>" + result[i].someValue1+ "</td>");
$('div[id="'+divId+'"]').append("<td>" + result[i].someValue2+ "</td>");
$('div[id="'+divId+'"]').append("<td>" + result[i].someValue2+ "</td>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found a solution for this issue. You can create your own Provider class which Jersey will use when generating the JSON response.

```
@Component
@Provider
public class 

JAXBContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {

private final JAXBContext context;

private final Class[] cTypes = { SomeCustomClass.class };

public JAXBContextResolver() throws JAXBException {
    this.context = new JSONJAXBContext(JSONConfiguration.natural().build(),
            cTypes);
}

public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
    for (Class type : cTypes) {
        if (type == objectType) {
            return context;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This provider uses the NATURAL JSON notation, which serializes the object as required in list format.

Ensure Spring is aware of the class by including the necessary annotations/bean definition

Answer (score 2):

Have your JSON return an object or array **always** (it may be empty if there are no results).

You can then iterate over the contents without needing to special-case zero, one, or more elements (you will always be using what is now your "multiple results" code path). And if you ever do need to special-case, it will also be trivial:

```
switch(result.length) {
    case 0:
    case 1: // etc
}
```

Comment: i return a List<customObject> from the server however if it only contains one entry it results in a single result in my JSON response

Comment: @linuxlewis: How is your JSON generated?

Comment: Using JSONWithPadding object from Jersey Rest API to wrap a custom object containing the list

Comment: the solution is to add a custom Provider which overrides the default JSON annotation Jersey uses to create the JSON response

Answer (score 0):

- Have `result` *always* be an array, even when it's empty or has just one element;
- Have `result[i]` contain an array instead of sequentially numbered properties, and iterate through it.